# page breaking in React to create pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-to-print

I am generating pdf using react-to-print library,

But i want to break the page in new page,

There is css property break-after:always, it can work, but not all major browser supports it now,

Anyone know any other method then brute force margin ?

Working with pdf is hard, specially css part.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after

Comment: Could you share the code you are currently trying please?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend to use React PDF npm library. Please check https://react-pdf.org